# How to train DeepLearning4J model Using a Java Object... Cant find assistance anywhere on this question

Tags: java, neural-network, training-data, opennlp, deeplearning4j

I am working on a Phrase Input and Response System (Similar to SIRI) want to train a Model on how to detect a phrase category, i.e. command, misc., special, using a Phrase[] Java object from Apache OpenNLP. How do I do that? my only experience with deeplearning4j with using .csv files to train models. **How do I use a set of java objects to train models? in DL4J?**

#### The examples i am looking at

The only experience with ML is apache Open NLP. And as for the examples, most of them are **Outdated** (the outdated ones are some of the first websites like baeldung.com or medium.com to pop up via google search)!

The other ones use Java dependencies that don't exist in my maven repositories (https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples) another reason, these don’t work, is that, the examples are for eclipse and i use Netbeans IDE, so i can’t just import the code and have it run, without some sort of problem.

I am using DeepLearning4J 1.0.0 Beta 7 and am using NetBeans IDE 12.0. The programming language i use for DL4J and Apache Open NLP is **Java**

#### Apache OpenNLP experience

I am familiar and use everything (all the way up to Parsing (#10 in the table of contents)) shown in the apache OpenNLP manual: (https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.9.3/manual/opennlp.html)

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit on what you're actually used to doing? Dl4j itself has tons of examples of setting up data for NLP. You typically have to know a bit about ML though.

Comment: The only experience with ML is apache Open NLP. And as for the examples, most of them are **Outdated**. I am using DeepLearning4J 1.0.0. Beta 7 @AdamGibson

Comment: Again, could you clarify where you're getting examples from? I'm still not even sure what you're referring to. Examples are all here: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples - and again, could you link to something concrete that represents a typical open nlp workflow for you? That would give me an idea on how to present a good example for you.

Comment: Yes the link you just posted is the one i use for examples. I updated the question and will be getting some of my NLP code and posting that soon as well @Adam Gibson